# Using API tags for a library

Tags: api, typescript

I'm currently creating a library for an API. The endpoints have optional tags, and so I'm trying to create a way to use them in the functions.

```
import * as request from "request";

class Api {
  key: string;
  constructor(userInput: string) {
    this.key = userInput;
  }

  champions(tags: object) {
    Object.keys(tags).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(key + " = " + tags[key])
    })

    request(`https://api.champion.gg/v2/champions?api_key=${this.key}&${tags}`, function (error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let info = JSON.parse(body)
      }
    });

  }
}

var test = new Api("key")
test.champions({"champData": ["kda", "damage"], "rawr": ["xd", "lmao"]})
```

So far, the combining of `Object.keys` and `forEach` has allowed me to get the response of `champData=kda,damage` and `rawr=xd,lmao`, however, I need to be able to assign these to a variable that's usable in the URL. How can I get this to work?

Another issue that may occur later on is that, between each tag, there needs to be an `&` symbol, but not at the end. I apologize for throwing multiple problems into one, but because this is my first experience with something like this, I'm having many issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `URLSearchParams()`

```js
const tags = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
const params = new URLSearchParams();
const key = "def";
Object.entries(tags).forEach(([key, prop]) => params.set(key, prop));
const url = `https://api.champion.gg/v2/champions?api_key=${key}&${params.toString()}`;
console.log(url);
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar without the URLSearchParams, and it returned the same error, `Property 'entries' does not exist on type ObjectConstructor` I believe it probably has something to do with TypeScript, and I'll fix the tag on it.

Comment: Have no experience using `TypeScript` here

Comment: Why do you not define a string before `.forEach()` and concatenate `"&" + key + "=" + tags[key]` to string?

Comment: Ooh, that's smart. But, that leaves me with my second problem; which might be fixable by using an if statement.

Comment: What is the second problem? Instead of hard coding the `"&"` character within template literal concatenate `"&"` is set  to beginning of each concatenated string within `.forEach()`

Comment: @UghThatGuyAgain `let params = "";

Object.keys(tags).forEach(key => params += "&" + key + "=" + tags[key])`